# Implement conversion operator for pointer

Tags: c++, operators

The question is simple but i can't find a solution.

```
class foo
{
public:
    operator int()
    {
        return 5;
    }
};

foo* a = new foo();   
int b = a;
```

Is it possible to implement that behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't. Conversion operators need to be members of a class, but `foo*` is not a user-defined class type, it's a pointer type (besides, `int b = *a` would work).

The best thing you can do is to use an utility function that does the casting.

Answer (score 1):

You can, by explicitly calling the operator:

```
foo* a = new foo();
int b = a->operator int();
```