# How can I write a C++ type conversion operator to implicitly convert all void* to MyStruct*

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm learning Windows driver dev, and find a problem using [VisualDDKHelper.h](http://visualddk.sysprogs.org/VisualDDKHelpers/) with C++ code(no problem with C code).

The question boils down to this:

```
// --- Formal Windows driver SDK header ---
typedef void * HANDLE;

// --- VisualDDKHelper.h ---
class HANDLE_VisualDDK_Helper { };
typedef HANDLE_VisualDDK_Helper *HANDLE_VisualDDK_Helper_t;

#define  HANDLE   HANDLE_VisualDDK_Helper_t // ★ VisualDDK HANDLE tweaker

// --- user code ---

void foo(HANDLE s) { }

//operator smy*()(void* ptr) { return (smy*)ptr; }
    // How can I write a type conversion operator so that user code compiles OK.

int main()
{
    char* s = "abc";
    class user_struct1 { int m; } *pu1 = 0;
    class user_struct2 { int m; } *pu2 = 0;

    foo(s);

    foo(pu1);
    foo(pu2); // lots of these

    return 0;
}
```

I'm really unwilling to convert all my driver code to something like:

```
foo((HANDLE)s);

foo((HANDLE)pu1);
foo((HANDLE)pu2); // lots of these
```

Can C++ operator overloading help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement conversion operator for pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802978/implement-conversion-operator-for-pointer)

Comment: I don't think you can. C++'s primary purpose in life is to prevent you from writing the user code you want to write, in which the same function `void foo(HANDLE_VisualDDK_Helper *)` can be passed either a `char*` or a `user_struct1*` without complaint. Certainly you cannot write a user-defined conversion from `void*` to another pointer type: you can only write user-defined conversion to and from user-defined types, and pointer types are not user-defined types even if the thing they point to is. It would work if `foo` took `void*`, it's just `VisualDDKHelper.h` has other ideas about `HANDLE`.

Comment: You could use templates to generically cast any argument type to a desired type. You can't cast a pointer to a user defined type to a value of that type though.
The question is why you want to do this and if this is generally a good idea.
C++ forbids this kind of thing for a reason. Usually you need to treat different types differently and for this case function overloading would provide a specialized handler for each type.
Without knowing what foo is actually supposed to be doing it's hard to give advice.