# cast operator between pointers

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

Given my own struct type `X`, is it possible to define an implicit cast operator that enables implicit conversion of `X*` to some other type, say `int*`. While casting between references is easy, I cannot find how to do it for pointers. Something like this:

```
struct X {
    int theContent;

    operator int&(){ return theContent; }
    operator const int&() const { return theContent; }

}

int main(){
   X x;
   X* x2=&x;
   // this should work, but it doesn't
   int* i=x2;
}
```

Comment: I think a similar question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802978/implement-conversion-operator-for-pointer). Answer is probably "no", as pointer is not a user-defined class type, so you cannot add cast operators for it.

Comment: You don't have an operator for casting `X*`to `int*`but only from `X` to `int&`. You can call the operator explicitly with `int* i=&x2->operator int&();`

Comment: @SimonKraemer: Well, I would not call that an *implicit* cast ;).

Comment: Definitely not ^^. BTW: You are missing a semicolon at the end of your struct.

Answer (score 0):

Your X is a standard layout type. You can simply `int* i=(int*)x2;` or (reinterpret_cast).

--

If a conversion has to be defined, then maybe something like

```
operator int*() { return &theContent; }
```

So you can `int* i=x;`.

Comment: @SimonKraemer my code is copied from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: I just wanted to add some more info/examples